# Floating point literal, floating literal, double Literal

Tags: java

Is the 'floating point literal' and the 'floating literal' the same thing in Java?

Also, is there anything called 'double literal' in Java?

Comment: Can you post the source text where you found this?

Comment: I never found it. I was reading about literals and it just occurred to me.

Comment: Here is the definition of floating-point literals: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Floating point literal" refers to any literal of a floating-point type.  Both `float` and `double` are floating-point types.

I have never come across the term "floating literal" before, but I would presume the intended meaning is the same as "floating point literal."  *You should make sure to ask for clarification though,* because if the author intended to say "float literal" then that would be a literal of type `float` in particular, and not just any floating-point type in general.

As for the specific type of floating-point literals in Java, all literals of the general form `#.#` are `double`, unless you append `f` or `F` (same difference) to the literal to force it to be `float` instead.

Check out the tutorial page on [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) by Oracle.  I've copied the sub-section titled "Floating-Point Literals" below.

> ### Floating-Point Literals
>
> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F
>   or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the
>   letter D or d.
>
> The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed
>   using E or e (for scientific notation), F or f (32-bit float literal)
>   and D or d (64-bit double literal; this is the default and by
>   convention is omitted).
>
> ```
> double d1 = 123.4;
> // same value as d1, but in scientific notation
> double d2 = 1.234e2;
> float f1  = 123.4f;
> ```

And as @Bubletan mentioned in comment to your question, if you're really curious you could check out the actual Java specification for float-point literals: [§3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

> Examples of `float` literals:
>
> ```
> 1e1f    2.f    .3f    0f    3.14f    6.022137e+23f
> ```
>
> Examples of `double` literals:
>
> ```
> 1e1    2.    .3    0.0    3.14    1e-9d    1e137
> ```

Comment: Okay so let me clarify......'floating point literal' refers to both float and double datatypes, 'float literal' refers specifically to the float datatype, and there is nothing (as per your knowledge) called 'floating literal'.

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti Correct.  Although I should clarify that "floating point literal" can refer to *any* floating-point data type.  (this is important because languages other than Java have more floating-point types than just `float` and `double`, e.g. [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)).

Answer (score 3):

Java has both `float` literals marked with a `f` suffix (for example, 2.5f) and `double` literals, which don't require a suffix (for example 2.5).

The difference between the two can be demonstrated when you attempt to assign such literals to variables :

```
double dl = 2.5; // passes compilation
float fl1 = 2.5; // error - "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float"
float fl2 = 2.5f; // passes compilation
```

Both can be considered as floating point literals, since both `double` and `float` are floating point types.

Answer (score 1):

"floating-point literal" will be float type if it ends with `F` or `f`; otherwise it is  a double