# integer number too large in arraylist

Tags: java

My ArrayList is like this, but I get an error "integer number too large".

```
testNet.setTrainSet(new double[][] { 

                { 1555760766,0.18 },{ 1555760766,0.3 },                
               { 1555760766,0.6 }, { 1555760766,0.6},

                { 2076569012,0.45 }, { 2076569012,0.64},
                { 2076569012,0.78 }, { 2076569012,0.98 },                             
                {2076569012,0.98 } ,  { 3265731800,0.1 }, 

                });
```

what is the solution?

Comment: do 3265731800L instead of 3265731800, that is tooo big to fit an integer.

Comment: The solution would be: do some prior research.

Comment: Ooh, Ghosty, cutting!

Comment: I changed too long ,but it still has an error,

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289696/floating-point-literal-floating-literal-double-literal/41289715

Comment: Why didn't  you just change it to double, since that's what you want?

Comment: Again: step back and **read** about the underlying concepts; such as the range of the different primitive data types. Dont do trial and error, **understand** what the keywords you type down **mean**

Comment: Come on, don't because I flag your question as duplicate so you downvote my old question. The link is really helpful for you.

Comment: your link was not helpful, I have read it before, and my question is not duplicate

Comment: Then you may explain why yours are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is that in java double literals end with a `d` if you didn't put `d` it will consider as an `integer`, hence integer no too large error will throw.

In this case you are missing `d`, so add `d` for the numbers which dont have a precision..

eg `double no = 1555760766d;`