# The constructor Game(String, int, int, double, String) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

So I am making a store in java and for some reason when doing class inheritance it says my constructor is undefined.

Below is my code

```
public class Store {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemArray;
    private int discount;

    public Store(String initName, int initDiscount) {
        name = initName;
        discount = initDiscount;
        itemArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Game item1 = new Game("Pokemon", 2000, 200, 4.5, "Nintendo");
        itemArray.add(item1);
    }
}

public class Item {
    public String name;
    public int price;
    public boolean taxable;
    public String category;
    public int inventory;

    public Item(String initName, int initPrice, boolean initTaxable, String initCategory, int initInventory) {
        name = initName;
        price = initPrice;
        taxable = initTaxable;
        category = initCategory;
        inventory = initInventory;
    }

    public void description() {
        System.out.println("This is a " + name);
        System.out.println("The base price is " + displayPrice());
        if (taxable) {
            System.out.println("This item is taxed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This item is not taxed");
        }
        System.out.println("This item is a " + category);
        System.out.println("There are " + inventory + " of this item left");
    }
    //Gets the price of the item before discounts(The price is in cents)
    public int getBasePrice() {
        return price;
    }
    //Gets the price of the item after discounts are applied the percentages should be in decimal form ex. .3 is 30% off
    public int getCurrentPrice(int discount) {
        int percentOfFullPrice = 100 - discount;
        double percentOfFullPriceDouble = percentOfFullPrice / 100.0;
        double finalPrice = percentOfFullPriceDouble * price;
        int finalIntPrice = (int) finalPrice;
        return finalIntPrice/100;
    }
    //Sets the new price of the item
    public void setPrice(int newPrice) {
        price = newPrice;
    }
    //Displays the price as a string
    public String displayPrice() {
        return "$" + (float) price / 100;
    }
    //Gets the inventory of the item
    public int getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    //Adds to the inventory of the item
    public int addInventory(int additionalInventory) {
        inventory += additionalInventory;
        return inventory;
    }
}

public class Game extends Item {
    public float reviews;
    public String companyBy;

    public Game(String initGameName, int initPrice, int initInventory, float initReviews, String initCompanyBy) {
        super(initGameName, initPrice, true, "Video Game", initInventory);
        reviews = initReviews;
        companyBy = initCompanyBy;
    }

    public void getReviews() {
        System.out.println("This video game has " + reviews + " out of 5 stars");
    }
    
}
```

I tried to initialize an object with parameters that would go to the superclass however, it seemed to get an undefined. If I initialize something simply using the Item class it works but I want different subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual constructor is `Game(String, int, int, float, String)`, notice *float*, while you provide it with *double* - `new Game("Pokemon", 2000, 200, 4.5, "Nintendo");`. The value `4.5` as literal is of type *double*. To make it a float, you need to use it like this - `4.5f` or `4.5F`.

```
new Game("Pokemon", 2000, 200, 4.5F, "Nintendo");
```

Check [Floating point literal, floating literal, double Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289696/floating-point-literal-floating-literal-double-literal) for more information.

Comment: The _reason_ for the error is correct. The provided solution is, effectively, wrong. The correct solution is to replace `float` with `double` in Item; not to add that F. There is no reason to use `float`. They are less precise and slower. If you store a ton of them in an array, that's... about the only argument left for them. Doesn't come up a lot.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I disagree, at the moment the example code does not suggest that `float` precision is not enough. It does not suggest enough operations, so that a performance boost from `double` will be noticeable, either. To be perfectly honest, considering it's a single field, the less occupied space by `float` is also unnoticeable. Long story short, my point is that there is not enough evidence to say, which solution is wrong and which correct (for this kind of homework like assignment, most probably it does not even matter).

Comment: You made just as much of an assumption in this answer. As you say, we have to go by basically no detail so either an answer should deep-dive into why that's an interesting choice, or, the answer should make the assumption it _is not_ an interesting choice (and it really isn't; the odds that it matters are effectively zero), or just assume the question would have mentioned it if it was important. Either way: Do the __default__ choice. And the default choice in java for 'I need floating point stuff' is: __use `double`__. This answer fails to apply this rule.